# How to run an R function getpoints() from IPDfromKM package in an R shiny app which in R pops up a plot that utilizes clicks to capture coordinates?

Tags: r, shiny, survival-analysis

I am trying to convert some R code I've written into an R shiny app so others can use it more readily.  The code utilizes a package called `IPDfromKM`.  The main function of issue is `getpoints()`, which in R will generate a plot and the user will need to click the max X and max Y coordinates, followed by clicking through the entire KM curve, which extracts the coordinates into a data frame.  However, I cannot get this to work in my R shiny app.

There is a [link](https://biostatistics.mdanderson.org/shinyapps/IPDfromKM/) to the working R shiny app from the creator

This is the getpoints() code:

```
getpoints <- function(f,x1,x2,y1,y2){

  ## if bitmap
  if (typeof(f)=="character")
      { lfname <- tolower(f)
       if ((strsplit(lfname,".jpeg")[[1]]==lfname) && (strsplit(lfname,".tiff")[[1]]==lfname) &&
            (strsplit(lfname,".bmp")[[1]]==lfname) && (strsplit(lfname,".png")[[1]]==lfname) &&
           (strsplit(lfname,".jpg")[[1]]==lfname))
         {stop ("This function can only process bitmap images in JPEG, PNG,BMP, or TIFF formate.")}
       img <- readbitmap::read.bitmap(f)
      } else if (typeof(f)=="double")
      {
        img <- f
      } else {
        stop ("Please double check the format of the image file.")
      }
  ## function to read the bitmap and points on x-axis and y-axis
  axispoints <- function(img){
    op <- par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
    on.exit(par(op))
    plot.new()
    rasterImage(img, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    message("You need to define the points on the x and y axis according to your input x1,x2,y1,y2. \n")
    message("Click in the order of left x-axis point (x1), right x-axis point(x2),
      lower y-axis point(y1), and upper y-axis point(y2). \n")
    x1 <- as.data.frame(locator(n = 1,type = 'p',pch = 4,col = 'blue',lwd = 2))
    x2 <- as.data.frame(locator(n = 1,type = 'p',pch = 4,col = 'blue',lwd = 2))
    y1 <- as.data.frame(locator(n = 1,type = 'p',pch = 3,col = 'red',lwd = 2))
    y2 <- as.data.frame(locator(n = 1,type = 'p',pch = 3,col = 'red',lwd = 2))
    ap <- rbind(x1,x2,y1,y2)
    return(ap)
  }

  ## function to calibrate the points to the appropriate coordinates
  calibrate <-  function(ap,data,x1,x2,y1,y2){
    x  <- ap$x[c(1,2)]
    y  <- ap$y[c(3,4)]
    cx <- lm(formula = c(x1,x2) ~ c(x))$coeff
    cy <- lm(formula = c(y1,y2) ~ c(y))$coeff
    data$x <- data$x*cx[2]+cx[1]
    data$y <- data$y*cy[2]+cy[1]
    return(as.data.frame(data))
   }

  ## take the points
  ap <- axispoints(img)
  message("Mouse click on the K-M curve to take the points of interest. The points will only be labled when you finish all the clicks.")
  takepoints <- locator(n=512,type='p',pch=1,col='orange4',lwd=1.2,cex=1.2)
  df <- calibrate(ap,takepoints,x1,x2,y1,y2)
  par()
  return(df)
}
```

I'm a bit at a loss in how to execute this in my main panel. I've tried using `plotOutput()`, `imageOutput()`, and calling variations of the below functions, but nothing pops up or seems to work like it does in R studio.  I feel like the issue is that the 'getpoints()' function executes 3 things :

1. Displaying an image from an uploaded file.
2. Allow user to click and store multiple points.
3. Return a data frame.

Will I need to split out the components of the function into individual steps?

```
createPoints<-reactive({
    
    #Read File
    file <- input$file1
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    req(file)
    validate(need(ext == "png", "Please upload a .png file"))
    
    ##should run the function that generates a plot for clicking coordinates and stores them in a data frame
    points<-getpoints(file,x1=0, x2=input$Xmax,y1=0, y2=100)
  
    return(points)
    
  })
```

```
output$getPointsPlot<-renderPlot(
    
    createPoints()
    
  )
```